# Cannot log in to server with POST request made in java

Tags: java, post, authentication, get, httpurlconnection

I am trying to make a Java program that, given the website, my username, and my password, logs in and read the html that the server will send back. In doing so I tried to simulate the browser request, so I tried to add the cookies the browser usually uses, put the User-Agent as Mozilla(etc), and all the other necessary headers, and in the body of the post request I put all the parameters that the server needs(username, password, a parameter that seems to be always the same, and another parameter that seems to change, and to find this by using the getValues() inside the paramsToString() functions, that creates the right string to be put intor the body.

In the login funciton I use other 3 functionsas follows:

1) listenWhatHeSays(conPrime) get the html that the server send me after the get request, and I use the information in this html to create my cookies and the payload.

2) paramsToString(getValues(response,name, password)) ->using the html response,it finds the payload(the string that need to be put into the body)

3) cookiesToString(GetCookiesFromHTTPConnection(conPrime)) -> using the html response, it cretes the string containing my cookies

My login function looks like this:

```
public String login(String site, String name, String password ) throws MalformedURLException, IOException  {
String url= site;
String payload,mycookies,response;
URL realUrl=new URL(url+"/login.php");
    HttpURLConnection conPrime = (HttpURLConnection) realUrl.openConnection();
    response=listenWhatHeSays(conPrime);
    payload=paramsToString(getValues(response,name, password));
    mycookies=cookiesToString(GetCookiesFromHTTPConnection(conPrime));

    HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) realUrl.openConnection();

            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
            con.setRequestProperty("Host", sito);
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.xyzsite.com");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",""+payload.length());
            con.setRequestProperty("Cookie",mycookies);
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            con.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            con.getOutputStream().write(payload.getBytes("UTF8"));

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine+'\n');

        }
        in.close();

        // print result
                     System.out.println();
                      System.out.println("conPrime response code: "+"  "+conPrime.getResponseCode()+" and message  : "+conPrime.getResponseMessage());
                      System.out.println("Con response code: "+"  "+con.getResponseCode()+" and message  : "+con.getResponseMessage());
        return response.toString();
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
                    return "POST request not worked";
    }


}
```

Now, using Wireshark, I analyzed the differences between the request made by the browser and my request. there are some differences:

1) the request I made creates 2 packages, that wireshark put together(show me 2 rassembled TCP segments), and the browser request is made only by one package. Why did my java program created 2 different packages? I didn't mean to do this. Can this be the problem?

2)the cookie SessinID is different in the 2 requests, but I thik this is ok since i made 2 different requests... am I right??

3) the parameter servertime that I need to put into the body is different in the 2 requests but I think this is normal since I make the requests in 2 differnt moments. (even tho...I dont understand how its encoded...an example is: 5a9857a72a881

Both HttpURLConnections "conPrime" and "con" gives me response code 200 OK, but as html response it gives me the login page, and NOT the page that should appear when you are already logged in. I don't know where to look to debug this...Why it don't give me the page that normally appears aftre you log in? Can it be the cookies? the payload is the same(a part for the servertime parameter)(I see this using wireshark), so I think it should be ok. What can be the problem? Do I need to send you guys something else?

Comment: Do you have HTTP authorization or via cookies ?

Comment: Why are people down voting this question? This seems like a genuine problem where a developer can get stuck.

Comment: Try removing the connection property to set the content-length.It might set the content-length on its own

Comment: @Marvin What means to have HTTP authorization or via cookies?

Comment: @Anoopsaju I tried both to remove and to put a hight number, but nothing changes :( it still sends 2 packeges.  What else can it be?

Comment: @Kortexar, to be short, does in browser popup login window, or you enter user/pass on a page ?

Comment: it don't pops up, it is the user/pass on the page